# How to hide/show a button based on other fields?

Tags: typescript, angular8

My requirement here is I want to hide/show a button based on few conditions. The requirement is I have a table where I have used checkbox to delete or update the status of an individual record, we can also select multiple records at the same time. Now, if I select multiple records and when any of the record selected contain status as close then we need to hide the button.

If status = 'Open', then we need to show the button but when we are selecting multiple records and any one of the record contains status other than open then we need to hide the button and there I'm facing the problem. And there are statuses more than 5 so we cannot write something like

```
*ngIf="status == 'Open' && status != 'close' ..."
```

I tried something like below, Storing all the available statuses in an array

```
availableStatus = ['Open','Close','Reject','On Process',...]
statusSelected = [contains statuses which are selected]
```

Now, comparing both the arrays and based on boolean value hiding and showing the button, but I think this isn't an effective way. Can someone suggest a better & efficient way.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Alizeh! I'm unfortunately not proficient in Angular but my experience with this site is that you'll get better answers if you provide an example. [Edit] your question and click on the "Snippets" button. Then you can type in HTML, JS and CSS like in jsfiddle. You can also select Angular on the left side of the screen. Create an example as far as possible and describe what behaviour you want to see and what you get instead!

Comment: @akraf-ReinstateMonica thank you I'll do that

Comment: I dont think there is a way to solve this, without comparing the two Arrays. I would probably write a method containing something like this: `this.statusSelected.every(val => val === 'Open')`

Comment: @Manox thanks for the reply, I have found the solution for it, I did something like below, `for (let index = 0; index < event.length; index++) {
      if(event[index].status != 'Open'){
        donotShowButtn = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(event && event.length > 0 && !donotShowButtn ){
      this.showBtn = true;
    }`

Comment: Great that you worked it out! You can post an answer to your own question if you want.